# Which would yield better performance in general?

Tags: vba, performance, excel, optimization

I have a small dilemma. As we all know, defining variables by types and avoiding the usage of variants is the most obvious performance trick. The problem is I'm trying to write a library of routines that would work with implicitly-typed arguments (basically variants).

Take for example:

```
Sub Test(A As String) ' Implicit ByRef
    Debug.Print A
End Sub
```

Nothing crazy, right? If I did `Test "ABC"`, it works as expected. The problem arises when I try to pass a value from an array (`Test Array("ABC")(0)`) or even a return value from another routine while chaining. I'd get a compile error saying "ByRef argument type mismatch".

I need these routines to take in various types of arguments and typecast them when possible. I then thought of the following:

```
Sub Test(ByVal A As String) ' Explicit ByVal
    Debug.Print A
End Sub
```

Now it works fine. So ultimately, my question is: is the performance gain achieved by explicitly defining argument types worth the tradeoff of the performance loss imposed by making copies of argument values from the use of `ByVal`? I know there will be cases where one would be better than the other, but for a general usage library, which method would be more suitable?

---

I have setup a small benchmark. I'm not exactly using the most powerful computer in the world (Core i3-2120, 32-bit Windows 7, 4 GB RAM), so I can't say these will apply for other setups.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub NoOp(ParamArray Self()) ' Adds a small overhead; not sure if there's a better built-in routine to use
End Sub

Private Sub ByReference(ByRef Argument As Variant) ' ByRef and As Variant are the default keywords if all keywords are ignored
    NoOp Argument
End Sub

Private Sub ByValue(ByVal Argument As String)
    NoOp Argument
End Sub

Private Sub Benchmark()
    Dim Index As Long, Argument As Variant: Argument = "ABC"
    A = GetTickCount / 1000
    For Index = 1 To 10000000
        ByReference Argument
    Next
    B = GetTickCount / 1000
    For Index = 1 To 10000000
        ByValue Argument
    Next
    Debug.Print B - A, (GetTickCount / 1000) - B ' Seconds; we get higher precision if we divide them before taking their differences
End Sub
```

Result: `3.88499999999476    4.99199999999837`

We can see a very obvious performance loss for a string (a short one, anyway).

Now, if I change `Argument` to `12345` and the routine definition's argument type to `Long`, I get:

Result: `4.07200000000012    4.05599999999686`

I don't know whether or not that's within the margin of error, but it does tell us that different types will behave differently.

Feel free to try different types on your own system and let me know.

Comment: If you only want to print things this will go just fine. However If you want to modify "A" you need to be carefull, as ByRef and ByVal might then result in different results. This: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx and this: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html might give you some insight.

Comment: Good point. I am aware of how ByRef and ByVal differ in that regard, but in this context, I am not looking to make changes to the input variables.

Comment: Speculating on the performance gain without a use-case is useless. That said, I tend to use `ByVal` when the size is close to the size of a pointer (Integer, Double...) and `ByRef` when it is greater (Array and Strings...).

Comment: Let's just say I have a convoluted system of calling routines given by their names as strings (using `Application.Run`). Small things along the chain would definitely add up when I call routines like these in large loops.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick test, have a look below. Calling `ByRef` is faster, which comes to no surprise, but the amount of time is so small that usually you really don't have to care. Tested on Win7 with a three years old laptop, so nothing fancy.

Running with 1 million iterations, result was 141 ms for `ByRef` and 281 ms for `ByVal`. Changing the string used as parameter every other time increased the time, but for both methods, so I assume that this is due to string handling.

**My conclusion: Choose calling method by your needs, not for speed.**

```
Option Explicit

Private mlngStart As Long
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub test()

    testPerformance 1000000, False
    testPerformance 1000000, True

End Sub

Sub testPerformance(iterations, changeString)
    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello World, this is a really long string to test what will happen when we pass it by value"
    StartTimer
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To iterations
        If changeString Then s = IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, "Hello world", "Hello World, this is a really long string to test what will happen when we pass it by value")
        Call f1(s)
    Next i
    Debug.Print iterations, changeString, "ByRef: " & EndTimer

    StartTimer
    For i = 1 To iterations
        If changeString Then s = IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, "Hello world", "Hello World, this is a really long string to test what will happen when we pass it by value")
        Call f2(s)
    Next i
    Debug.Print iterations, changeString, "ByVal: " & EndTimer

End Sub

Sub f1(ByRef s As String)
    '
    If s = "X" Then
        Debug.Print s
    End If
End Sub

Sub f2(ByVal s As String)
    If s = "X" Then
        Debug.Print s
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub StartTimer()
    mlngStart = GetTickCount
End Sub

Public Function EndTimer() As Long
    EndTimer = (GetTickCount - mlngStart)
End Function
```

output:

```
 1000000      False         ByRef: 141
 1000000      False         ByVal: 281
 1000000      True          ByRef: 655
 1000000      True          ByVal: 764
```

Comment: Let's say I want to define an optional string parameter. Since `vbNullString` uses no memory, should I define it like `Optional Param As String = vbNullString` or leave it as `Optional Param As String`?

Comment: I don't think that this makes any difference. No clue how exactly the compiler handles optional parameter, but I would think that it puts something like `NULL` on the stack, probably the same as `vbNullString`. Anyhow, putting a value on the stack is a cheap operation, I wouldn't care about that and always do what fits best to my programming.